# Change My.Settings ConnectionString in runtime?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, connection-string

I have a ClickOnce deployment where i have a INI-settings file on the network file with "global" settings that is supposed to affect the program on all client computers.
The problem i have is that i whant to have the Database connectionString stored in this INI file and have it read and stored in the My.Settings ConnectionString at program startup. How do i do this? The ConnectionString setting is Application scoped and therefore Read-Only, if i try to set it by  `My.Settings("ConnectionString") = "Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True"`
I get a runtime error:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for
>   details.  The error is: The type initializer for 'DB_lib.DB_LINQ'
>   threw an exception.

[EDIT]
I got rid of the error by using the `My.Settings("ConnectionString") = "Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;Integrated Security=True"` in another place then the the eventtriggerd settingsLoaded method i created.. The problem is that even though the connectionstring semes to be the right, the program still connects to the "default" database that is typed in to the app.config file??

Comment: Why do you use 'My.Settings("ConnectionString")' and not the strong typed version 'My.Settings.ConnectionString'?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change application-settings from within your application. Change it to a user setting.

Or write your own settings (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx)):

> If you want more detailed control over your settings, you can define
>   your own custom applications settings wrapper class. This is
>   accomplished by deriving a class from [ApplicationSettingsBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx), adding
>   a property that corresponds to each setting, and applying special
>   attributes to these properties. For details about creating wrapper
>   classes, see [Application Settings Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to change a ConnectionString from application to user scoped? In the settings tab, under the "Scope" column, there is no dropdownlist for ConnectionStrings, it is set to Application by default and i cant change it to User there.

Comment: @Sultanen: I assume you want to change the settings of your own application. In 'Using Application Settings and User Settings' <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750> you can read how to use them. If you show us some more code we eventually could give you a better hint what's going wrong.